# If value is true show modal1, if value is false show modal2 react-js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

I have two modal windows. The first window with congratulations that stretch from the api. If there are no holidays, a second modal window with promotions is shown. How can I implement this? It seems that I'm doing something wrong, because the modal windows are not displayed correctly
maybe I'm pulling data from the state incorrectly

```
its main page 

import { ModalAd } from "../../components/modal/modalAd/ModalAd";
import { HolidaysModal } from "../../components/holidaysModal/holidays";

const NewsPage = () => {
  const holidays = useSelector((state) => state.addHoliday);
  return (
    <div className="NewsPage">{holidays ? <HolidaysModal /> : <ModalAd />}</div>
  );
};
```

```
this is my redux state with api

export const GetHoliday = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: HOLIDAY_IS_FETCHED,
    payload: true,
  });
  try {
    let addHoliday = (
      await axios.get(`${config_backend.host}/api/news/holiday.php`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: getAuthorization(),
        },
      })
    ).data;

    dispatch({
      type: HOLIDAY_IS_FETCHING,
      payload: false,
    });

    dispatch({
      type: HOLIDAY_IS_FETCHED,
      payload: true,
    });
    if (addHoliday.success) {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_HOLIDAY,
        payload: addHoliday.result.data,
      });
    } else {
      console.log('err');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch({
      type: HOLIDAY_IS_FETCHING,
      payload: false,
    });

    dispatch({
      type: HOLIDAY_IS_FETCHED,
      payload: false,
    });

    dispatch({
      type: GET_HOLIDAY,
      payload: null,
    });

    console.log('err');

    dispatch({
      type: GET_HOLIDAY,
      payload: null,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean, the modal windows are not displayed correctly? What exactly is happening? Also, if you inspect the `holidays` const, does it hold the value you expect?

Comment: @Shawn: modal1 pops up, but modal2 doesn't pop up.  i get a window with congratulations, but if i remove the api for example, the second window won't pop up

Comment: whether correctly I get the data from the state?  Or maybe it's because I wrote if else incorrectly?

Comment: @Shawn: const holidays works fine, I get success:true, no problem with it.  the problem is that the second modal doesn't want to show up

Comment: I think that's your problem. If `holidays` is an object, it will always be truthy and you'll never seen the second modal (ModalAd). Maybe what you need is a different conditional, something like this: `holidays.success === true ? <HolidaysModal /> : <ModalAd />`

Comment: Otherwise, it's like doing `{ success: true } ? <HolidaysModal /> : <ModalAd />` which will always return `<HolidayModal />` no matter what's in the object.

Comment: Try this for example: `console.log({success: false} ? 'truthy' : 'falsy') // logs 'truthy'`

Answer (score 0):

I think `holidays` is an object and not a boolean, which explains why isn't always truthy and you never see the ModalAd.

Try this conditional instead:

```
holidays.success === true ? <HolidaysModal /> : <ModalAd />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing `GetHoliday` is your reducer. If yes, try this way.

```
const holidays = useSelector((state) => state.GetHoliday);
```

in your main page and return `addHoliday` result so that `GetHoliday` has this value.

```
if (addHoliday.success) {
  return addHoliday.result.data
}
```